# ¿Por qué no puedo marcar como duplicada una pregunta que no tiene respuestas aceptadas o con votos positivos?

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

Todo ha venido con la siguiente pregunta [Precargar imagenes en página web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308953/precargar-imagenes-en-p%c3%a1gina-web?noredirect=1#comment562542_308953) en la cual el OP pregunta sobre precargar imágenes en la web.

Casualmente, me he acordado de que respondí una pregunta similar hace tiempo, aunque sin que me la marcaran como aceptada ni con votos positivos [Como quitar parpadeo al cargar imágenes en slideshow?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156042/como-quitar-parpadeo-al-cargar-im%C3%A1genes-en-slideshow/) entonces le he mencionado en comentarios al OP de la primera pregunta que igual esa respuesta le podía ayudar.

Me ha respondido que era justo lo que necesitaba y la he ido a marcar como pregunta duplicada, pero, sin embargo, y para mi sorpresa, no me ha dejado porque no hay ninguna respuesta aceptada o con votos positivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Tiene sentido que impidamos marcar una pregunta como duplicada por el simple hecho de que no hay ninguna respuesta que tiene votos positivos? Hay veces que hay preguntas que pasan desapercibidas por la comunidad pero quizá alguien pregunte lo mismo en el futuro y podamos enlazarlo a la pregunta original.

Comment: En estos casos tiene poco sentido, efectivamente. Supongo que se pretende que la pregunta canónica tenga cierto empaque y la métrica que usan es que alguna de las respuestas haya tenido utilidad. Sin la marca de aceptar ni votos positivos, se puede entender que no es el caso.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, parece que ahora sí tiene algún voto positivo... :)

Comment: @fedorqui Y ya he visto que la has marcado para cerrar como duplicada :P

Comment: @fedorqui Y si, entiendo el motivo que dices de que la pregunta canónica tenga cierto valor aunque para casos como este no tiene sentido. La verdad es que nunca me había ocurrido esto y tampoco esperaba que me fuera a bloquear el marcarla como duplicada xDD